# SaaS, PaaS solution for RF applications

Tags: cloud, platform, rfid, wifi, zigbee

I'm looking for SaaS/PaaS solution in the cloud, which will enable rapid deployment, provisioning and support of wireless applications based on ZigBee, RFID and maybe WLAN clients.

I don't want to bother myself with development and deployment of end-to-end infrastructure + there is a need for further expansion of new RF-based features in this system.

Ideally I'm looking for something like Twilio (twilio.com) or gadget/widget based application platform in the cloud, which will enable rapid application development and deployment. For sure, open API and some application examples should be present.

Any advices here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [iDigi](http://www.idigi.com).  iDigi is a hosted PaaS/SaaS which allows you to communicate and manage remote wireless devices.  In short:

1) Devices connect to iDigi and become securely and globally accessible, even if they are behind a NAT.

2) You can communicate with one or more devices using simple web-service requests.

3) The iDigi web interface allows you to manage remote device configurations, set alarms, perform firmware and application updates for one or thousands of devices.

It works with Digi International's hardware, such as their ConnectPort X cellular wireless gateways *and* with your own third-party hardware via their connection agent known as the [iDigi Connector](http://www.idigi.com/idigiconnector/).

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. But it looks like Digi solutions, including iDigi, are focused on ZigBee based technologies only. Right? And there is no application-level frameworks and API available in iDigi Cloud. What I'm really looking for - cloud platform, which will enable deployment of heterogenous wireless applications in one place: WLAN, Bluetooth, ZigBee, RFID etc. Cloud service will connect to some edge gateways through TR-069, OMA-DM or SNMP for handling device/network management.